# Derivation of the equation of Right Strophoid

Tags: curves

The equation of the right Strophoid is given as $y^2(a+x)=x^2(a-x)$ and the parametric equations are: $$
x=a\sin t=a\cos u\\
y=a\tan t(1-\sin t)=a\cos u\tan\frac{u}{2}
$$

**Attempt**

[image: stpd]

According to the definition th right Strophoid is the locus of points $P(x,y)$ for which $|O'Q|=|PQ|$

Let $\angle PON=\theta$
$$
\sin\theta=\frac{PN}{PO}=\frac{O'Q}{OQ}=\frac{MQ}{PQ}\\
\cos\theta=\frac{NO}{PO}=\frac{O'O}{OQ}=\frac{PM}{PQ}\\
\tan\theta=\frac{PN}{ON}=\frac{QM}{PM}=\frac{O'Q}{OO'}=\frac{O'Q}{a}=\frac{PQ}{a}
$$
$$
x^2=PM^2=PQ^2-QM^2=PQ^2-PQ^2\sin^2\theta=PQ^2\cos^2\theta=a^2\tan^2\theta.\cos^2\theta=a^2\sin^2\theta\\
\implies\color{red}{\boxed{x=a\sin\theta}}
$$
$$
\frac{PN}{QM}=\frac{PO}{PQ}\\
y^2=PN^2=\frac{PO^2}{PQ^2}.QM^2=\frac{PO^2}{a^2\tan^2\theta}.QM^2=\frac{PO^2}{a^2\tan^2\theta}.PM^2\tan^2\theta\\
=\frac{}{a^2\tan^2\theta}.a^2\sin^2\theta\tan^2\theta\\
=PO^2\sin^2\theta
$$

How do I solve for $y$ here ?

Comment: Form your diagram it is evident that $PO=QO-QP=QO-QO' $. We also have  $QO=\frac{a}{\cos \theta}$ and $QO'=a\tan \theta$. Therefore, $PO=\frac{a}{\cos \theta}-a\tan \theta$. I think you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
y^2&=PO^2-ON^2\\
&=\frac {y^2}{\sin^2\newcommand{\t}{\theta}\t}-(a-a\sin\t)^2.
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
y^2\left (\frac{\sin^2\t-1}{\sin^2\t}\right)&=-a^2 (1-\sin\t)^2.
\end{align*}
Now, it is easy to see that $$y=a\tan\t (1-\sin \t). $$